# Rails: Duplicate route tree; is there a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my rails application I have two trees that are identical but mounted in two points:

```
resources :organizations do

  large_routing_tree

  resources :projects do
    large_routing_tree
  end
end
```

The large_routing_tree includes around 10 resources with nesting.

Is there a better way to do this than copy-pasting the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean

```
resources :organizations do 
  resources :projects, :shallow => true do
    large_routing_tree
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for, but it wouldn't work for me because the :projects also has routes that should not be available to :organizations.